# Как лучше хранить таблицу?

Tags: javascript, java

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой вопрос: как мне лучше всего сохранить таблицу - прямо в коде или в файле, из которого она будет подгружаться, если таблица имеет такой формат:

```
  1 2 3 4 5
1 
2   
3
4
5
```

Вместо цифр будут имена, а поля будут заполнены процентами.  
108 на 108 ячеек,изменяться не будут.
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В коде хранить, если предполагаются неизменяемые данные, тогда можно создать константный массив массивов (массив массивов, массив векторов, вектор массивов, вектор векторов, мэпов и т.п. - далее просто массив).
2. Если данные должны часто и активно менятся, но не сохраняться, то можно держать в неконстаном массиве и, например, изменять каждую "ячейку" в отдельном потоке (не знаю, что там за задача).
3. Если нужно часто менять и сохранять, подгружай из файла или бд в массив, там меняй и снова сохраняй.
4. Если нужно редко менять и сохранять, то можно напрямую сохранять каждую ячейку каждый раз при изменении и грузить все из файла/бд при необходимости отображения (если действительно 5 на 5, то можно).

---

Какая бы ни была задача, другие варианты представить трудно.

---

P.S. А вообще лучше бы описывать задачу детализированней.

Comment: Уточнил мало,каюсь.
Просто 108 на 108 массив объявить сразу заполненным накладно.Если подгружать - в чём хранить?

Comment: если нужен произвользный доступ к каждой ячейки при загрузке, то в любой базе данных, не принципиально. Формат, например может быть такой (в базе): номер строки, номер столбца, значение (или же для каждого столбца свое поле в базе, если "смысл" этих столбцов неоднороден, но я так понял речь идет о какой-то матрице где все ячейки имеют один тип данных?). Если нужно просто последовательно считать все, то в любом формате в файле: бинарник, xml... Не исключено что и в базе, если удобно